# How to restart pyspark streaming query from checkpoint data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am creating a spark streaming application using pyspark 2.2.0

I am able to create a streaming query

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
      .builder \
      .appName("StreamingApp") \
      .getOrCreate()

staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("parquet")\
.option("inferSchema","true").load("processed/Nov18/")

staticSchema = staticDataFrame.schema
streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream\
.schema(staticSchema)\
.option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1)\
.format("parquet")\
.load("processed/Nov18/")

daily_trs=streamingDataFrame.select("shift","date","time")
.groupBy("date","shift")\
.count("shift")

writer = df.writeStream\
   .format("parquet")\
   .option("path","data")\
   .option("checkpointLocation","data/checkpoints")\
   .queryName("streamingData")\
   .outputMode("append")

query = writer.start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

The query is streaming and any additional file to "processed/Nov18" will be processed and stored to "data/"

If the streaming fails I want to restart the same query

**Path to solution**

1. According to official documentation I can get an id that can be used to restart the query
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=streamingquery#pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery.id
2. The pyspark.streaming module contains StreamingContext class that has classmethod

   classmethod getActiveOrCreate(checkpointPath, setupFunc)
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.StreamingContext.getOrCreate

can these methods be used somehow?

*If anyone has any use case of production ready streaming app for reference ?*

Comment: What happens when you simply start the app again (after it was stopped)? Does this not behave as requested? What's missing?

Comment: ohh ..! it was that simple ..thank you. I thought it is some how related to that streamingContext. Do you know or have any use case of production ready streaming app for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply (re)start the pyspark application with the checkpoint directory available and Spark Structured Streaming does the rest. No changes required.

> If anyone has any use case of production ready streaming app for reference ?

I'd ask on the [Spark users mailing list](http://spark.apache.org/community.html).